# REGEXP Name Validation

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to get a regexp to validate that an input field "Full Name" doesn't have any numbers or special characters. only alphabets. The issue is I want it to validate the input in several languages not only English.
Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: What about `O'Brian` or `Jean-François`?